# First and Second guessings are the same

Tags: java, android, numbers

I am new to Java and I am developing a Number Guessing Game. When I click the random button , I get a random number that's okay but When I try this second time, second and first random numbers are the same.

How can I solve it? Here is my code:

```
int KullaniciTahmini;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView Sayi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sayi);
    Button Tamam = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Tamam);
    final Button Rastgele = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Rastgele);
    final EditText Tahmin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tahmin);
    final int gizliSayi = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * 100);

    Rastgele.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int random = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
            Sayi.setText("Lutfen 0 ile 100 arasinda bir deger giriniz!");
        }
    });

    Tamam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int KullaniciTahmini = Integer.parseInt(Tahmin.getText().toString());

            if (KullaniciTahmini < gizliSayi) {

                Sayi.setText("Degeri Buyult");
            }

            if (KullaniciTahmini > gizliSayi) {

                Sayi.setText("Degeri Kucult");
            }

            if (KullaniciTahmini == gizliSayi) {

                Sayi.setText("Dogru Cevap!");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only assign to `gizliSayi` once, in `onCreate`:

```
final int gizliSayi = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * 100);
```

I think you want to remove the `final` there and then update that value in `Rastgele.setOnClickListener` by changing this line:

```
int random = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
```

to this:

```
gizliSayi = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
```